# How to update properties of riot tags?

Tags: riot.js

I've created a riot tag which renders many svg elements in loop

```
<circle ref={ keyName } each={ point,keyName in opts.points } ></circle>
```

Now I've two conditions

1. Update a particular tag
2. Update all the tags

To update properties of a particular tag, I' m using `this.refs[ someName ].setAttributes("cx", 30);`

To update properties of all the tags should I use the above approach in loop? or I should update `opts.points` and call `this.update()`.

Comment: Have you found a solution to this one?

Comment: No I didn't find the direct solution. So I'm using jQuery for that.

Answer (score 0):

You only need to update your list opts.points and riot.js will change the html without you refer to each item using jQuery as you commented.

Check if the opts.lists are updating, this probably is your problem, but you can solve this doing something like:

```
 <circle ref={ keyName } each={ point,keyName in this.points } ></circle>
 <script>
    this.points = opts.points // the parent component is providing a list

    someFunction() {
       this.points = ["something", "whatever", "another thing"]
       this.update()
    }
</script>
```